# UIWebView show partial website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to load an URL, but want to show only the contents inside a certain div and hide everything else on the website.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Webview you can inject JS. Like this you will be able to hide the content you want :)

Here's a link to help you : https://gist.github.com/irace/3688560

PS : if your app is iOS7 compatible as well, than look at this : http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

Comment: That actually worked, had to inject JS after the WebView loaded